# Breaking a forloop in django

Tags: python, django

I am currently working on a dna to protein translator. The code works pretty well. However, I'd like to improve it with some if statements:

Here's the views.py code where I type the if statements:

```
class TranslatorView(View):
    template_name = 'main/translated.html'

    amino_mapper={
        "aat": "Asparagine",
        "aac": "Asparagine",
        "aaa": "Lysine",
        "aag": "Lysine",
        "act": "Threonine",
        "acc": "Threonine",
        "aca": "Threonine",
        "acg": "Threonine",
        "agt": "Serine",
        "agc": "Serine",
        "aga": "Arginine",
        "agg": "Arginine",
        "att": "Isoleucine",
        "atc": "Isoleucine",
        "ata": "Isoleucine",
        "atg": "Methionine",
        "cat": "Histidine",
        "cac": "Histidine",
        "caa": "Glutamine",
        "cag": "Glutamine",
        "cct": "Proline",
        "ccc": "Proline",
        "cca": "Proline",
        "ccg": "Proline",
        "cgt": "Arginine",
        "cgc": "Arginine",
        "cga": "Arginine",
        "cgg": "Arginine",
        "ctt": "Leucine",
        "ctc": "Leucine",
        "cta": "Leucine",
        "ctg": "Leucine",
        "gat": "Aspartic",
        "gac": "Aspartic",
        "gaa": "Glutamic",
        "gag": "Glutamic",
        "gct": "Alanine",
        "gcc": "Alanine",
        "gca": "Alanine",
        "gcg": "Alanine",
        "ggt": "Glycine",
        "ggc": "Glycine", 
        "gga": "Glycine",
        "ggg": "Glycine",
        "gtt": "Valine",
        "gtc": "Valine",
        "gta": "Valine",
        "gtg": "Valine",
        "tat": "Tyrosine",
        "tac": "Tyrosine",
        "taa": "Stop",
        "tag": "Stop",
        "tct": "Serine",
        "tcc": "Serine",
        "tca": "Serine",
        "tcg": "Serine",
        "tgt": "Cysteine",
        "tgc": "Cysteine",
        "tga": "Stop",
        "tgg": "Tryptophan",
        "ttt": "Phenylalanine",
        "ttc": "Phenylalanine",
        "tta": "Leucine",
        "ttg": "Leucine",
        "AAT": "Asparagine",
        "AAC": "Asparagine",
        "AAA": "Lysine",
        "AAG": "Lysine",
        "ACT": "Threonine",
        "ACC": "Threonine",
        "ACA": "Threonine",
        "ACG": "Threonine",
        "AGT": "Serine",
        "AGC": "Serine",
        "AGA": "Arginine",
        "AGG": "Arginine",
        "ATT": "Isoleucine",
        "ATC": "Isoleucine",
        "ATA": "Isoleucine",
        "ATG": "Methionine",
        "CAT": "Histidine",
        "CAC": "Histidine",
        "CAA": "Glutamine",
        "CAG": "Glutamine",
        "CCT": "Proline",
        "CCC": "Proline",
        "CCA": "Proline",
        "CCG": "Proline",
        "CGT": "Arginine",
        "CGC": "Arginine",
        "CGA": "Arginine",
        "CGG": "Arginine",
        "CTT": "Leucine",
        "CTC": "Leucine",
        "CTA": "Leucine",
        "CTG": "Leucine",
        "GAT": "Aspartic",
        "GAC": "Aspartic",
        "GAA": "Glutamic",
        "GAG": "Glutamic",
        "GCT": "Alanine",
        "GCC": "Alanine",
        "GCA": "Alanine",
        "GCG": "Alanine",
        "GGT": "Glycine",
        "GGC": "Glycine", 
        "GGA": "Glycine",
        "GGG": "Glycine",
        "GTT": "Valine",
        "GTC": "Valine",
        "GTA": "Valine",
        "GTG": "Valine",
        "TAT": "Tyrosine",
        "TAC": "Tyrosine",
        "TAA": "Stop",
        "TAG": "Stop",
        "TCT": "Serine",
        "TCC": "Serine",
        "TCA": "Serine",
        "TCG": "Serine",
        "TGT": "Cysteine",
        "TGC": "Cysteine",
        "TGA": "Stop",
        "TGG": "Tryptophan",
        "TTT": "Phenylalanine",
        "TTC": "Phenylalanine",
        "TTA": "Leucine",
        "TTG": "Leucine",
    }

    
    stop_codon= {
        "taa":"Stop",
        "tag":"Stop",
        "tga":"Stop",
        "TAA": "Stop",
        "TAG": "Stop",
        "TGA": "Stop",
    }



    
    def translate_amino(self, codon):
        return self.amino_mapper.get(codon, "")


   

    def build_protein(self, request, phrase):
        if len(phrase) % 3:
            messages.error(request, 'CHAIN MUST BE DIVISIBLE BY 3')
            return ()
        protein = []
        for i in range(0, len(phrase), 3):
            codon_stop= self.stop_codon.get(phrase)
            amino = self.translate_amino(phrase[i: i + 3])
            if amino:
                protein.append(amino)
            elif not amino:
                messages.error(request, "PROTEIN WAS NOT FOUND")
                return ()  
            elif codon_stop: #Here's where I think the error is:
                break
            
            
        return protein
```

What I want to do is if the function detects a phrase from stop_codom, the for loop should break. However, the for loop still continues.
[image]

If the code worked correctly, it should've stopped at the STOP

Comment: Apparently `codon_stop` is an empty string. What did you find when you debugged this code?

Comment: I found that the forloop was still running

Comment: I have changed that and the forloop still doesn't break

Comment: And why did you expect that `codon_stop` has a value that is different from the empty string (or None, after your change in the code), which would cause the `break` statement to be executed?

Comment: Honestly, the empty string was misplaced. So it never had to be there. Still, the for loop doesn't break

Comment: Anyway, in order to execute `break`, `codon_stop` would need to be something "truthy" (i.e., not an empty string or None), which means, as it is the result of looking up `phrase` in `self.stop_codon`, `phrase` must be equal to one of the keys in `self.stop_codon`. Why did you expect this is the case?

Comment: Because it sounded more pythonic, to be honest. Anyways, I'd like to get all the keys from the self.stop_codon. How would you do it?

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood my previous comment. Let's try differently: when you print the value of `phrase` just before `codon_stop = self.stop_codon.get(phrase)`, what exactly do you get as output?

Comment: Ok, I've edited the post so you can see it. Sorry for not understanding the question before, I'm a bit blocked right now

Comment: Where exactly does the word `STOP` come from in the code you have shown? It doesn't appear anywhere in the code.

Comment: I've just added the dictionary for that in the post . Check it out

Comment: So you want to abort the loop if `amino` is equal to `"Stop"`?

Comment: Yes, I want to break the loop. However, I don't know how to do it

Comment: Well... why not: `if amino == "Stop": break`?

Comment: I tried that before and it didn't work.

Comment: And does it work now?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. Any other clues to what might the solution be?

Comment: What happens then? Where did you put it?

Comment: It happens the same as the image I posted in the thread: Threonine, stop, threonine

Comment: Ok, I put the if statement above and it finally worked. I must have in mind the python order in the next projects. Anyways, thanks a lot

Comment: You should read this: [mre], and this: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/